# Здравствуйте , не пойму , как делать лабу

Tags: c++

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, что конкретно от меня требуется в лабораторной. Условие лабы очень трудно воспринимается.

Что из себя должен представлять этот алгоритм сортировки?

Код лабы не требую, пожалуйста, помогите понять условие задачи и сам алгоритм!

```
Лабораторная работа №10: Задача о библиотекаре
Цель: освоение некоторых специфических алгоритмов обработки массивов и методов
работы с текстовыми файлами.
Задачи:
• ознакомиться с методами чтения и записи файлов, содержащих текстовую
информацию;
• разобрать очередной подход к обработке массивов.
Задание: Библиотекарь – пожилой мужчина, работающий в библиотеке. На любимой
книжной полке библиотекаря расположены N<201 книг. Ежедневно (библиотека работает
даже в выходные дни!) нерадивые читатели устремляются к любимой книжной полке
библиотекаря и хватают оттуда книги, после чего в течение определенного времени
читают их, и к концу дня ставят обратно на полку в случайном порядке.
Библиотекарь не может допустить, чтобы книги в конце дня располагались на
полке не в алфавитном порядке, поэтому он считает своим долгом переставить их для
упорядочивания. В молодости библиотекарь мог без труда и с большим удовольствием
упорядочить книги хоть на целом стеллаже! Но теперь… Руки-то уж не те. Библиотекарь
желает минимизировать количество своих действий, потраченных для упорядочивания
книг на любимой полке. Одно его действие заключается в том, что библиотекарь
извлекает книгу с полки и ставит ее на полку в другое место, между какими-либо двумя
другими книгами.
Книги на полке могут быть и одинаковые.
Исходные данные представлены в виде текстовой информации о книгах, которая
находится в файле input.txt.
Рекомендуемый вид консоли:
Исходный файл:
Пушкин А.С. «Евгений Онегин»
Тургенев И.С. «Отцы и дети»
Логинов С.В. «Свет в окошке»
Пушкин А.С. «Евгений Онегин»
Стругацкий Б.Н., Стругацкий А.Н. «Понедельник начинается в субботу»
Янссон Т.С. «Волшебная зима»
Тургенев И.С. «Отцы и дети»
Толстой Л.Н. «Война и мир»
Отсортированная информация:
2. Пушкин А.С. «Евгений Онегин»
5. Тургенев И.С. «Отцы и дети»
1. Логинов С.В. «Свет в окошке»
2. Пушкин А.С. «Евгений Онегин»
3. Стругацкий Б.Н., Стругацкий А.Н. «Понедельник начинается в субботу»
6. Янссон Т.С. «Волшебная зима»
5. Тургенев И.С. «Отцы и дети»
4. Толстой Л.Н. «Война и мир»


1. Логинов С.В. «Свет в окошке»
2. Пушкин А.С. «Евгений Онегин»
2. Пушкин А.С. «Евгений Онегин»
3. Стругацкий Б.Н., Стругацкий А.Н. «Понедельник начинается в субботу»
4. Толстой Л.Н. «Война и мир»
5. Тургенев И.С. «Отцы и дети»
5. Тургенев И.С. «Отцы и дети»
6. Янссон Т.С. «Волшебная зима»
Массив:
 2 5 1 2 3 6 5 4
1 2 1 2 3 4 4 4
Библиотекарю необходимо выполнить 4 действия.
Книги, которые останутся на месте:
2. Пушкин А.С. «Евгений Онегин»
5. Тургенев И.С. «Отцы и дети»
1. Логинов С.В. «Свет в окошке»(эта)
2. Пушкин А.С. «Евгений Онегин»(эта)
3. Стругацкий Б.Н., Стругацкий А.Н. «Понедельник начинается в субботу»(эта)
6. Янссон Т.С. «Волшебная зима»
5. Тургенев И.С. «Отцы и дети»
4. Толстой Л.Н. «Война и мир»(эта)
```

Comment: эх.............

Answer (score 0):

задача:

1. считать названия книг из файла в массив, запоминая номер строки в файле (пары элементов: строка, число)
2. отсортировать эти пары элементов в алфавитном порядке названий книг (предоставить оператор сравнения для пары элементов и запихать массив пар в std::sort)(или отсортировать пары элементов в алфавитном порядке ручками)
3. сравнить отсортированный массив: если текущее положение пары (индекс в массиве) не равен запомненному значению (числовое значение из пары), то вывести на экран эти книги, как требующие перемещения; иначе вывести на экран как НЕ требующие перемещения